# How to rotate/translate/flip vtkActor2D object using vtk?

Tags: c++, opengl, vtk

I have a vtkActor2D object that I wish to rotate/translate/flip. Is there a simple way to
rotate/translate/flip about its center?

Comment: You can find a lot of examples at [http://www.itk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx) . Look for Rotate a 2D image.

Comment: Hi JohnnyQ. It's for vtkImageActor. Not for vtkActor2D :(

Comment: i don't know diffrence from each vtkactor type.

Answer (score 1):

For `vtkActor2D`, use `SetPoint(float, float)` (lower left) and `SetPoint2(float, float)` (upper right) to control the position. Note that this will allow you to rotate the prop as well, but you'll have to to do the math yourself, or use
`vtkCoordinate` that Actor2D gives you.